# How to external url forwarding via GCP https load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to redirect our load balancer IP address to an external website. Such as 10.2.2.3 to abc.com, My main aim is that I will call 10.2.2.3/house.jpg in the web browser, and then I will receive an answer from abc.com/house.jpg . How can I do that with GCP HTTPS load balancer?

Comment: Is private IP mandatory? Can you detail the type of load balancer you use?

Comment: this guide seems to be similar to your case scenario https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https